# XGBoost giving slightly different predictions for list vs array, which is correct?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, xgboost

I noticed I was passing a double bracket list of test feature values for

```
print(test_feats)
>> [[23.0, 3.0, 35.0, 0.28, -3.0, 18.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.33, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 39.0, 36.0, 113.0, 76.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.34, -999.0, -999.0, -999.0, -999.0, -999.0, -999.0, -999.0, -999.0, 0.0, 25.0, 48.0, 48.0, 0.0, 29.0, 52.0, 53.0, 99.0, 368.0, 676.0, 691.0, 4.0, 9.0, 12.0, 13.0]]
```

I notice when I pass this to XBGBoost for prediction it returns a different results when I turn it to an array

```
array_test_feats = np.array(test_feats)
print(regr.predict_proba(test_feats)[:,1][0])
print(regr.predict_proba(aray_test_feats)[:,1][0])
>> 0.46929297
>> 0.5161868
```

Some basic checks suggest values are the same

```
print(sum(test_feats[0]) == array_test_feats.sum())
print(test_feats == array_test_feats)) 
>> True
>> array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

I am guessing the array is the way to go, but I really don't know how to tell. The predictions are close enough that it could easily slip by so I really would like to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just run into the issue described here: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/3970

> The documentation does not include lists as an allowed type for the
>   data inputted into DMatrix. Despite this, a list can be passed in
>   without an error. This change would prevent a list form being passed
>   in directly.
>
> I experienced an issue where passing in a list vs a np.array resulted
>   in different predictions (sometimes over 10% relative difference) for
>   the same data. Though these differences were infrequent (~1.5% of
>   cases tested), in certain applications this could cause serious
>   issues.

Essentially, what's happening under the hood is that passing Python lists directly is not officially supported in XGBoost but happens to work anyway because it hits [a fall through case](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/c89bcc4de5368b3f8a7fa170d8348287dab44caf/python-package/xgboost/core.py#L476-L483) in XGBoost's data conversion.

This causes XGBoost to use the `XGDMatrixCreateFromCSREx` function instead of `XGDMatrixCreateFromMat` to create the underyling matrix for the data. There is then a [difference in behavior](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1634) between the missing elements in the sprase vs dense representations:

> "Sparse" elements are treated as "missing" by the tree booster and as
>   zeros by the linear booster.